First 4-Layer PCB: SPI Testing with DSO - Misconfigured SPI Lines or PCB Design Flaw?
This is my first 4 layer PCB which has a tof sensor in the middle which uses SPI. Now the issue is before permanently soldering the sensor I wanted to make sure if MCU’s SPI lines are good or not. The design and firmware was open source and initially when MCU is powered on it sends some test sequence and expect something in return. check the test sequence here. Now I was at least expecting that CS should go low and MOSI should give the exact test sequence. So I connected the DSO to check the SPI lines.

Here ch1-clk ch2-mosi ch3-cs ch4-miso (here i am assuming since slave is not connected it is showing something different it's voltage was 14 mV) rest of the pin had 3.023 V including CS pin (in the PCB design I added a diode after LDO which 0.3 V drop down hence 3.032 and not 3.3 V). Another thing I am concerned is if there is something wrong with the PCB design itself, I know for differential pairs like USB traces needs to be close but for SPI I didn't thought or study too much and routed poorly according to the space that I had.

from this can anyone make sense out of the dso or is it total garbage. And does this DSO reading at least tells that SPI lines are functional? Well I know SPI lines doesn't look like this and also I don't really know how to use the DSO properly so.. Can someone suggest better way to test these SPI lines before I solder the sensor??
sorry i didn't took any good images of probing I am still figuring out how to use dso properly

basically 7_gnd is connected to all probe's gnd idk if that right or not, rest spi lines are connected to the probe directly 10x.

as you can see I already messed up with mosfet

Have you checked for shorts between CS and SCLK? e.g. a solder bridge given they are adjacent on the IC. Or maybe CS is floating due to bad solder joint. Either way it shouldn't be oscillating like that

initially yes i checked it and there wasn't but after connecting the probe I didn't. (https://imgur.com/a/3aJkjkf) I have added more images from another dso I don't remember the channels here don't know if it makes any sense

Best way to check pins like this is to make a little test program that makes one of those four pins an output, the rest input and oscillates that pin at a given speed (e.g. 5MHz). Then probe that ONLY that pin is oscillating, none of the others. Also, if you're starting out, don't use 25MHz for SPI, start at 1MHz or something until you get it working.
There's a lot of noise on the lines, be sure that the probe ground is connected to the board near the SPI lines. On all boards that I design I like to include a GND lug (Keystone 5015 or similar) to be able to do this.
Finally, with nothing attached to the end of the SPI lines they're going to look a little funky; a better test would be to add (at the U3 location, only for testing) a 1kOhm to GND on all lines and then look at the SPI.
Layout isn't great; the ground pads up near top are quite odd. Also the traces look pretty wide since they're almost as wide as the SMT pads.
Also I usually put in small value (e.g. 22 ohm) series resistors at the source of all SPI lines. Helps with ringing a little but also in case I made a mistake.
